# Get outer this-context without loosing inner one

Tags: typescript

I need to have access to two this-contexts at the same time

```
export class ToolSelectionComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('toolGroupGrid') public grid: GridComponent;

  public tools: Tool[] = [...];
  public toolGroups: { Id: number, Name: string }[] = [...];
  public toolsGroupAssignments: { GroupId: number, ToolId: bigint }[] = [...];

  public childGrid: GridModel | GridComponent = {
    columns: [...],
    load() {
      const grid = this as GridComponent;
      const groupId = grid.parentDetails.parentRowData['Id'];
      grid.dataSource = outerThisAsVariable.tools.filter(t => t.groupId === groupId);
    }
  };

  ...
}
```

For some reason I don't know when defining `load` this way `this` returns different values than `childGrid` when defining load as a callback and binding `this`. So I have to define `load` this way. But how do I get access to the outer variables at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the value in an immediately invoked function and pass the component that way, e.g.:

```
export class ToolSelectionComponent {
  public parentProp = 42;

  public childGrid = (component => ({
    columns: 3,
    load() {
      const grid = this;
      
      console.log(grid.columns);
      console.log(component.parentProp);
    }
  }))(this);
}
```

Alternatively you can move the assignment of the `childGrid` to the `contructor`, where you will also have access to the component as `this` and can assign it to a local variable which can be used in `load()`.

This is actually the compiled JS of the above code (unless the flag [`useDefineForClassFields`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useDefineForClassFields) is turned on):

```js
export class ToolSelectionComponent {
    constructor() {
        this.parentProp = 42;
        this.childGrid = (component => ({
            columns: 3,
            load() {
                const grid = this;
                console.log(grid.columns);
                console.log(component.parentProp);
            }
        }))(this);
    }
}
```